# One error when import data from Hive cluster to solr6.2 cluster

Tags: solr, hive, solrcloud

There are 2 clusters for hive and solr.
I want to import data from hive table in hive cluster to solr cluster.
When the num of fields configured in managed-schema file is about 34 then import successfully, once the num larger than 34(the num is 44) , i will meet exception of connection reset. 
Exception info as follow:

```
{"id":{"name":"id","value":"176036","boost":1.0},
"_id":{"name":"_id","value":"176036","boost":1.0}
... 44fields in json format ...
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient$RouteException: IOException occured when talking to server at https://ip:port/solr/gp19edamp_qxb_administrative_punishment_all_cs1_shard2_replica1
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:886)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:857)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:181)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity.writeTo(BufferedHttpEntity.java:115)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:216)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:686)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:488)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at com.huawei.solr.client.solrj.impl.InsecureHttpClient.execute(InsecureHttpClient.java:143)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:644)
    ... 10 more
```

You know there is no build-in limit. The limit is going to be dictated by your hardware resources.
Hope your answers~

Comment: Can you clarify? Please ask proper question.

Comment: I edited the question , hope for  your answer